# C# while loop involving DateTime variable not performing calculations

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm currently working on a project that utilizes DateTime variables to find the cost of travel between a variety of dates. Most of the click event will fire but the calculations for total price and average price won't run. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime arrival = DateTime.Parse(txtArrivalDate.Text);
            DateTime departure = DateTime.Parse(txtDepartureDate.Text);                      
            TimeSpan numDays = departure - arrival;
            int ndays = numDays.Days;
            txtNights.Text = ndays.ToString();
            decimal totalPrice = 0;
             txtTotalPrice.Text = totalPrice.ToString("c");
            decimal avprice = totalPrice / ndays;
             txtAvgPrice.Text = avprice.ToString("c");
            DateTime nightToCharge = arrival;
            decimal pricePerNight = 0m;
            int i = ndays;
            while (i > 0)
            {
                DayOfWeek dayOfweek = nightToCharge.DayOfWeek;
                if (dayOfweek == DayOfWeek.Friday ||
                    dayOfweek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                {
                    pricePerNight = 150m;
                }
                else
                {
                    pricePerNight = 120m; 
                }
                i--;
                nightToCharge = nightToCharge.AddDays(1);
                totalPrice += pricePerNight;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I can tell you already your problem --> `int ndays = numDays.Days;`. You need to use `TotalDays`. Used that and if you still have issues repost question with clear problem

Comment: It looks like you are calculating `totalPrice` and then throwing away the result. Add `txtTotalPrice.Text = totalPrice.ToString()` after the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your prices aren't being shown because you're setting the value of the `TextBox` text *before* you calculate the price. You're also setting the average price before you calculate the total.

Just calculate the average and assign the price values after the `while` loop:

```
while (i > 0)
{
    // Code omitted for brevity
}

decimal avprice = totalPrice / ndays;
txtTotalPrice.Text = totalPrice.ToString("c");
txtAvgPrice.Text = avprice.ToString("c");
```